# How do I extract a remote tarball on to local machine

Tags: linux, redhat, tar, remote-server, system-administration

I have a remote repository of all required tarballs. I need to ***run a command on local linux machine to fetch this remote tarball and extract locally***.

I know how to extract a local tarball on a remote machine but here, how do i achieve the the **opposite using ssh**?

I do not want to mount any remote directory nor want traces of tar file on local machine. Is this possible?

Comment: You probably have some level of confusion around terminology. You don't extract 'remote tarball onto local machine'. You download then extract then remove tarball.

Comment: Use `scp` to fetch the remote tarball, then extract it locally. If the remote machine accepts `ssh` connections, it probably accepts `scp` as well.

Comment: @marekful: See my answer, you can do what OP asked for.

Comment: Kindly please, edit your post to fits what is your need, for file transfer, you can use [Secure copy- scp](https://linux.die.net/man/1/scp) for SSH based access, or [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html) for HTTP / web access (matching question title). For remote machine access and make an actions, there is probably not other way, then connect via [ssh](https://www.openssh.com/manual.html) and remotely run local script

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can use `ssh` to get the  file content and pipe it straight to tar to extract it on the local machine without actually putting the tarball onto the local filesystem:

```
ssh remotehost cat /path/to/foo.tar.gz | tar xzf -
```

Be sure you're in the desired output directory first.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for that.btw

Comment: Any idea how to retain the ownership of extracted files if extraction is done as super user? **--same-owner** doesn't seem to work.
`ssh remotehost cat /path/to/foo.tar.gz | tar xzf - --same-owner`

Comment: @AnrupNarik: You're saying you run the entire command (ssh and tar) as root?  `man tar` says `--same-owner` is the default when run as superuser.  Maybe you can try `ssh ... | sudo tar xzf -`.  I'm not sure though.